# Get JSON file and push in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

In my data storage folder is a JSON file. I save the device id to the local storage of the broswer:

```
//Store deviceID in local storage on button click
function store(){
    var inputDeviceID= document.getElementById("deviceID");
    localStorage.setItem("deviceID", inputDeviceID.value);
}
```

I get the device id with a javascript function and push it with ajax into my php script to load the corresponsing data:

```
function localstoragecheck(){
    if (localStorage.getItem("deviceID") === null) {
        //alert('no');
    }
    else {
        //alert('yes');

        var deviceIDcookie = localStorage.getItem("deviceID");

        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            data: {'deviceID': deviceIDcookie},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            complete : function(){
               // alert(this.url)
               $.getJSON("/sigfoxdata/" + deviceIDcookie + ".json", function(json) {
                   console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
               });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PHP code for searching the json file and decode it:

```
$FOLDER = '../sigfoxdata/';
$dir = scandir($FOLDER);
$file = $_GET['deviceID'].'.json' ?: 'DEMO.json';
$fileUrl = $FOLDER.$file;

$file = fopen($fileUrl, "rip");
$lines =  fread($file, filesize($fileUrl));
$data = json_decode($lines)->{'data'};
```

But this is not working, how can I get data from the ajax request in the PHP script?

Comment: Have you tried to output `$_GET` with `print_r($_GET);`? This shows you, what actually was sent to your PHP file. And why do you use `jsonp`?

Comment: if the content of the file is already JSON, you dont need to json_decode. Just replace your open and read with `$data = file_get_contents($fileUrl);`. BTW, you should check beforehand whether the file exists and is readable by the PHP process.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg `file_get_contents` will not decode JSON automatically.

Comment: @Barmar OP keeps mentionning the `json file` ... i'm thinking the content of the file is already json.

Comment: What is the `'rip'` argument to `fopen()`? `r` is for read-mode, but what are `i` and `p`?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg And if it's already JSON, you need to use `json_decode()` to convert it from JSON to an object or array.

Comment: Why roll your own database this way and not simply use a proper database that is simple to query?

Comment: The PHP script is never echoing the JSONP response, it needs `echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');';`

Comment: And the Javascript `complete:` function never uses the response from the server.